# Laravel Route Says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found

Tags: laravel, routes

Laravel Route Says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Hello Thanks In Advance Please Someone help me iam trying from two days to solve this problem but nothing gives me any help.

my routes are ok but when iam change routes then they gives this message

`[Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.]`

My Routes :

```
// The first one is working perfectly
Route::get('/', function () { return view('TeacherShow'); }); 
// But the second one is not working
Route::get('/a', function () { return view('TeacherShow'); });
```

what can i di?

Comment: is mod_rewrite enabled in your Apache server?

Comment: sir where is this mod_rewrite in apache please send me the path iwill be very thinkfull from last 2 days iam searching iam new here

Comment: php artisan route:clear will clear cached routes

Comment: i had tried may times clearing cache but

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the rewrite module is enabled:

sudo a2enmod rewrite

Make sure you restart Apache after editing a configuration file or enabling a new module so that the changes take effect.

Comment: sir how and where to add this

Comment: In your .htaccess file in the public folder. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62572847/13619485  answer by Qaisar Shabir with clearer instructions.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**
Check mod_rewrite is enabled or not. Execute below command to anable it.

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

After that restart server.

```
service apache2 restart
```

**Solution 2**
AllowOverride should be set to All, not None. If you installed apache2.4

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**Solution 3**
This solution based on ".htaccess" file. So mod_rewrite should be enabled, otherwise it will not work.
Create a file named ".htaccess", past these lines in that file and put that file in the below path
"app/public/"

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] </IfModule>
```

**Solution 4**
If you installed laravel 9. Rename server.php to index.php from your project root directory and move ".htaccess" file from public directory to root directory with below script.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
      Options -MultiViews -Indexes
   </IfModule>

   RewriteEngine On

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
   RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: sir but in my laravel projectinside the public folder there is alredy a .htaccess file can i remove that one

Comment: No, just edit that file and put these lines of code in it. Remove prior code from it